# Grid-auto-row necessary when using grid-template-areas?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is grid-auto-rows unecessary when you use grid-template-areas to define your layout? I was quite convinced this was still the case, but deleting that part of the code I wrote seems to not affect the overall site-layout at all. I am asking about this in general, the code is merely an example.

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
    grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav"
    "area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 "
"area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 "
"area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 "
"area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 area1 "
"area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 "
"area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 area2 "
  "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining any `grid-template-rows` so yes it's needed if you want to set the height of your rows. Without it, each row will have its height defined as `auto` but probably in your case `minmax(50px,auto)` is also using the `auto` part since `50px` is smaller than your content. In case of empty rows, you will have `50px`.

Here is an example to see the difference:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
    grid-template-areas:
    "nav "
    "area1 "
"area1"
"area1"
"area1 "
"area2  "
"area2 "
  "footer ";
  margin:10px;
}
.nav {grid-area:nav}
.area1 {grid-area:area1}
.area2 {grid-area:area2}
.footer {grid-area:footer}

.wrapper > div {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="area1"></div>
<div class="area2"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="grid-auto-rows: minmax(10px, auto);">
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="area1"></div>
<div class="area2"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

> The three properties `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and `grid-template-areas` together define the explicit grid
>
> The size of the explicit grid is determined by the larger of the number of rows/columns defined by grid-template-areas and the number of rows/columns sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns`. Any rows/columns defined by grid-template-areas **but not sized** by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` take their size from the `grid-auto-rows` / `grid-auto-columns` properties.  <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)</sup>